# OLEDB Inserting a row in excel before the header columns of create table

Tags: excel, oledb

I am using oledb to create excel sheets.

I use create table to create a excel sheet.
This creates a new sheet, as well as add the column names in first row of the sheet.

I want to add a title before this first row how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Once the sheet is created - with create table.
2. Insert the data.
3. Close connection.
4. now open connection with HDR=no in extended properties.
5. now execute an update query

   Update F1='new value' where F1='old value'
6. in above because of the HDR=no, the column names are available as data row, executing update allowed changing row. Here F1 equals first column and so on.